# How to use overlapping floating div's?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm making a Wordpress theme with PHP, HTML and CSS.
My footer automatically floats down under the white content block when more text is added.

Now, I want to add another image that has to overlap the footer and also the white content block.
But... I want it to float down when more text is added, like the footer does.

Here's the link to make my question clear:
[website](http://protoformat.nl/wordpress/visie/)

So, I want the image with the papers and the pencil to overlap both of the div's footer and the white content block. And it also needs to float down when more text is added.

oh, and I'm also having an issue with the outer edges of my footer, as you can see there is space, but the footer has to be full screen at the width.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the footer already aligns and "floats" as the content changes, the simplest solution would be to take advantage of this and place it inside the footer. From there you can position it partially outside with absolute positioning on the illustration and relative positioning on the footer.

Here's a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/eliland/Qp76P/

Answer (score 2):

Before going into the answers, I advise you to do 2 things:

1. validate your CSS, because from a very fast overview I spotted a typo at line 25 `min-heigt` which must be `min-height`
2. use CSS resets before any custome CSS. For this, check http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
   Personally I use normalize.css from http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/

One more thing, and this is my opinion: there are plenty of cleaner themes out there which you can use to build your child theme. They include the latest in modern Web techniques, SEO, etc. E.g. Thematic, twentytwelve, twentyeleven, etc. And for free ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Didn't notice the spelling error, thanks for that too. I've used a CSS reset before, but it's not really working for my custom WP theme.

Comment: welcome. Can you tell us why it is not working? Or what do you mean by it is not working? A CSS reset is supposed to start you off from a common baseline on all different browsers. That is to mainly override browser defaults.

Comment: I know, but because I'm working on a Wordpress Theme it won't be linked on the other files. If I not follow "the rules" of making a WP Theme, i'll get many errors, so I prefer don't use reset.css... (it also is my first time that I making such a thing as a WP theme, so I don't want to ruin it ;))